# dfply: Mutating string column: TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, dfply

My pandas dataframe contains a column "file" which are strings with a file path. I am trying to use dfply to mutate this column like

```
resultstatsDF.reset_index() >> mutate(dirfile = os.path.join(os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(X.file)),os.path.basename(X.file)))
```

but I get the error

```
TypeError: __index__ returned non-int (type Call)
```

What did I do wrong? How do I do it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since my question was up-voted, I guess, it is still interesting to some people. Having learned quite a bit in Python so far, let me answer it, maybe it is going to be helpful to other users.

First, let us import the required packages

```
import pandas as pd
from dfply import *
from os.path import basename, dirname, join
```

and make the required pandas DataFrame

```
resultstatsDF = pd.DataFrame({'file': ['/home/user/this/file1.png', '/home/user/that/file2.png']})
```

which is

```
                        file
0  /home/user/this/file1.png
1  /home/user/that/file2.png
```

We see that we still get an error (though it changed due to continuous development of dfply):

```
resultstatsDF.reset_index() >> \
mutate(dirfile = join(basename(dirname(X.file)), basename(X.file)))
```

> TypeError: **index** returned non-int (type Intention)

The reason is, because mutate works on series, but we need a function working on elements. Here we can use the function [pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) of pandas, which works on series.
However, we also need a custom function that we can apply on each element of the series `file`.
Everything put together we end up with the code

```
def extract_last_dir_plus_filename(series_element):
    return join(basename(dirname(series_element)), basename(series_element))

resultstatsDF.reset_index() >> \
mutate(dirfile = X.file.apply(extract_last_dir_plus_filename))
```

which outputs

```
   index                       file         dirfile
0      0  /home/user/this/file1.png  this/file1.png
1      1  /home/user/that/file2.png  that/file2.png
```

Doing this without dfply's `mutate`, we could write alternatively

```
resultstatsDF['dirfile'] = resultstatsDF.file.apply(extract_last_dir_plus_filename)
```