# pandas merge on date column issue

Tags: python, pandas, merge, data-manipulation

I am trying to merge two dataframes on date column (tried both as type `object` or `datetime.date`, but fails to give desired merge output:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 =  pd.DataFrame({'amt': {0: 1549367.9496070854,
      1: 2175801.78219801,
      2: 1915613.1629125737,
      3: 1703063.8323954903,
      4: 1770040.7987461537},
     'month': {0: '2015-02-01',
      1: '2015-03-01',
      2: '2015-04-01',
      3: '2015-05-01',
      4: '2015-06-01'}})
print(df1)


        amt             month
    0   1.549368e+06    2015-02-01
    1   2.175802e+06    2015-03-01
    2   1.915613e+06    2015-04-01
    3   1.703064e+06    2015-05-01
    4   1.770041e+06    2015-06-01



df2 =  {'factor': {datetime.date(2015, 2, 1): 1.0,
      datetime.date(2015, 3, 1): 1.0,
      datetime.date(2015, 4, 1): 1.0,
      datetime.date(2015, 5, 1): 1.0,
      datetime.date(2015, 6, 1): 0.99889679025914435},
     'month': {datetime.date(2015, 2, 1): datetime.date(2015, 2, 1),
      datetime.date(2015, 3, 1): datetime.date(2015, 3, 1),
      datetime.date(2015, 4, 1): datetime.date(2015, 4, 1),
      datetime.date(2015, 5, 1): datetime.date(2015, 5, 1),
      datetime.date(2015, 6, 1): datetime.date(2015, 6, 1)}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
print(df2)

                factor      month
    2015-02-01  1.000000    2015-02-01
    2015-03-01  1.000000    2015-03-01
    2015-04-01  1.000000    2015-04-01
    2015-05-01  1.000000    2015-05-01
    2015-06-01  0.998897    2015-06-01


pd.merge(df2, df1, how='outer', on='month')

        factor       month            amt
    0   1.000000     2015-02-01      NaN
    1   1.000000     2015-03-01      NaN
    2   1.000000     2015-04-01      NaN
    3   1.000000     2015-05-01      NaN
    4   0.998897     2015-06-01      NaN
    5   NaN           2015-02-01    1.549368e+06
    6   NaN           2015-03-01    2.175802e+06
    7   NaN           2015-04-01    1.915613e+06
    8   NaN           2015-05-01    1.703064e+06
    9   NaN           2015-06-01    1.770041e+06
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need first convert both columns [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) because need same `dtypes`:

```
df1.month = pd.to_datetime(df1.month)
df2.month = pd.to_datetime(df2.month)

print (pd.merge(df2, df1, how='outer', on='month'))
     factor      month           amt
0  1.000000 2015-02-01  1.549368e+06
1  1.000000 2015-03-01  2.175802e+06
2  1.000000 2015-04-01  1.915613e+06
3  1.000000 2015-05-01  1.703064e+06
4  0.998897 2015-06-01  1.770041e+06
```

---

```
#convert to str date column
df2.month = df2.month.astype(str)

print (pd.merge(df2, df1, how='outer', on='month'))
     factor       month           amt
0  1.000000  2015-02-01  1.549368e+06
1  1.000000  2015-03-01  2.175802e+06
2  1.000000  2015-04-01  1.915613e+06
3  1.000000  2015-05-01  1.703064e+06
4  0.998897  2015-06-01  1.770041e+06
```

Comment: There is problem you cannot match string column with date column - need same dtypes.

Comment: but I get ``df1.month.dtype`` = ``dtype('O')`` and 
    ``df2.month.dtype`` = ````dtype('O')````, so if both are string types then why would it matter

Comment: yes, you are right, because `date`, `list`, `set`, `str` all are object - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42672574/2901002)

Comment: conversion to str did not help,  conversion to ``pd.to_datetime()`` did

Comment: and it is a bit confuse - `dtype` is object, but `type` not

Comment: I had the same issue...converting it both to a datetime object did it