# pandas merge on date like columns does not work

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pandas, datetime, merge

first, the solution didn't work in my code [pandas merge on date column issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812216/pandas-merge-on-date-column-issue)

I have two data frame comes from mysql query result, both of them have 'captureDate' column. In mysql table, the data type is 'date'. In the data frame, the data type is object.

df1['captureDate'] data

```
0    2017-06-28
1    2017-06-28
2    2017-06-28
3    2017-06-28
4    2017-06-28
5    2017-06-28
6    2017-06-28
Name: captureDate, dtype: object
```

df2['captureDate'] data

```
0    2017-06-28
1    2017-06-28
2    2017-06-28
3    2017-06-28
4    2017-06-28
5    2017-06-28
6    2017-06-28
Name: captureDate, dtype: object
```

when I compare the column of df1 and df2, it returns True

```
print df1['captureDate'].equals(df2['captureDate'])
```

my merge code

```
inner = pd.merge(df1, df2,  on='captureDate', how='inner')
```

but, the result is wrong, it returned 49 rows. The inner info is blow:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 49 entries, 0 to 48
Data columns (total 20 columns):
rule_id_x          49 non-null int64
monitor_sites_x    49 non-null object
rule_type_x        49 non-null int64
lower_limit_x      49 non-null int64
upper_limit_x      49 non-null int64
actual_x           49 non-null int64
predict_x          49 non-null int64
captureDate        49 non-null object
deviation_x        49 non-null float32
create_time_x      49 non-null int64
actual_y           49 non-null int64
create_time_y      49 non-null int64
deviation_y        49 non-null object
id                 49 non-null int64
lower_limit_y      49 non-null int64
monitor_sites_y    49 non-null object
predict_y          49 non-null int64
rule_id_y          49 non-null object
rule_type_y        49 non-null int64
upper_limit_y      49 non-null int64
```

so, why it happens and how to handle this issue?

Comment: There is problem with duplicates. Simpliest solution is remove duplicates. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'captureDate':['2017-06-22'] *3 +['2017-06-25'] * 3 +['2017-06-28'] * 2,
                   'rule_id':[40,10,20,30,70,10,60,10]})
print (df1)
  captureDate  rule_id
0  2017-06-22       40
1  2017-06-22       10
2  2017-06-22       20
3  2017-06-25       30
4  2017-06-25       70
5  2017-06-25       10
6  2017-06-28       60
7  2017-06-28       10
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'captureDate':['2017-06-22'] *3 +['2017-06-25'] * 3 +['2017-06-28'] * 2,
                   'rule_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
print (df2)
  captureDate  rule_id
0  2017-06-22        1
1  2017-06-22        2
2  2017-06-22        3
3  2017-06-25        4
4  2017-06-25        5
5  2017-06-25        6
6  2017-06-28        7
7  2017-06-28        8
```

First convert to datetime by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df1['captureDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['captureDate'])
df2['captureDate']  = pd.to_datetime(df2['captureDate'])
```

---

Problem are duplicates in both columns:

```
print (df1['captureDate'].equals(df2['captureDate']))
True

inner = pd.merge(df1, df2,  on='captureDate', how='inner')
print (inner)
   captureDate  rule_id_x  rule_id_y
0   2017-06-22         40          1
1   2017-06-22         40          2
2   2017-06-22         40          3
3   2017-06-22         10          1
4   2017-06-22         10          2
5   2017-06-22         10          3
6   2017-06-22         20          1
7   2017-06-22         20          2
8   2017-06-22         20          3
9   2017-06-25         30          4
10  2017-06-25         30          5
11  2017-06-25         30          6
12  2017-06-25         70          4
13  2017-06-25         70          5
14  2017-06-25         70          6
15  2017-06-25         10          4
16  2017-06-25         10          5
17  2017-06-25         10          6
18  2017-06-28         60          7
19  2017-06-28         60          8
20  2017-06-28         10          7
21  2017-06-28         10          8
```

**Possible solutions**

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then flatten `MultiIndex` by `map` and `join`:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.set_index('captureDate'), 
                 df2.set_index('captureDate')], 
                 axis=1, 
                 keys=('a', 'b'))
df3.columns = df3.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df3)
             a_rule_id  b_rule_id
captureDate                      
2017-06-22          40          1
2017-06-22          10          2
2017-06-22          20          3
2017-06-25          30          4
2017-06-25          70          5
2017-06-25          10          6
2017-06-28          60          7
2017-06-28          10          8
```

Or remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) or aggregation of data by `captureDate` in both `df`:

```
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('captureDate')
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates('captureDate')
print (df1)
  captureDate  rule_id
0  2017-06-22       40
3  2017-06-25       30
6  2017-06-28       60

print (df2)
  captureDate  rule_id
0  2017-06-22        1
3  2017-06-25        4
6  2017-06-28        7

inner = pd.merge(df1, df2,  on='captureDate', how='inner')
print (inner)
  captureDate  rule_id_x  rule_id_y
0  2017-06-22         40          1
1  2017-06-25         30          4
2  2017-06-28         60          7
```

EDIT1:

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count duplicates by column `captureDate` and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html). Last remove helper column `new` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'captureDate':['2017-06-22']* 3 + ['2017-06-25']* 3 + ['2017-06-28'] * 2,
                   'rule_id':[40,10,20,30,70,10,60,10]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'captureDate':['2017-06-22'] * 3 + ['2017-06-25'] * 3,
                   'rule_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})


df1['new'] = df1.groupby('captureDate').cumcount()
df2['new'] = df2.groupby('captureDate').cumcount()
print (df1)
  captureDate  rule_id  new
0  2017-06-22       40    0
1  2017-06-22       10    1
2  2017-06-22       20    2
3  2017-06-25       30    0
4  2017-06-25       70    1
5  2017-06-25       10    2
6  2017-06-28       60    0
7  2017-06-28       10    1

print (df2)
  captureDate  rule_id  new
0  2017-06-22        1    0
1  2017-06-22        2    1
2  2017-06-22        3    2
3  2017-06-25        4    0
4  2017-06-25        5    1
5  2017-06-25        6    2
```

---

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['captureDate','new']).drop('new', axis=1)
print (df3)
  captureDate  rule_id_x  rule_id_y
0  2017-06-22         40          1
1  2017-06-22         10          2
2  2017-06-22         20          3
3  2017-06-25         30          4
4  2017-06-25         70          5
5  2017-06-25         10          6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Well, I want the df3 result. But two frames have different columns number, it cant be 'concat'

Comment: I used to merge two date like columns, and it works. why it didnt this time?

Comment: So `print (df1['captureDate'].equals(df2['captureDate']))` is False?

Comment: It's True. I am so confusing about why it can not be merge on these two same columns. By the way, I tried to transfer captureDate into str type, and they still equal to each other, while, still can not merge. Strange. @jezrael

Comment: cumcount works. I will try try to figure out the rest of questions.Thank you for your time and your patience. Have a nice day.

Comment: @vera - Thank you very much, for you too!