# str.replace function creating NaN data

Tags: pandas

I am trying to replace certain strings in a column in pandas, but am getting `NaN` for some rows. The column is an object datatype.

I want all rows with `'n'` in the string replaced with `'N'` and and all rows with `'s'` in the string replaced with `'S'`. In other words, I am trying to capitalize the string when it appears.

However, I am am getting `NaN` values for rows without `'n'` or `'s'` in the string. **How can I replace `'n'` and `'s'` without getting `NaN` for the other values?**

Here is the head of my dataframe:

```
data_frame['column_name'].head(10)
0      1n
1      1n
2      1n
3      1n
4      2n
5      2s
6       3
7       3
8      4s
9      4s
```

After replacing, the string `'3'` is now `NaN`:

```
data_frame['column_name'] = data_frame['column_name'].str.replace('n', 'N')
data_frame['column_name'] = data_frame['column_name'].str.replace('s', 'S')

data_frame['column_name'].head(10)
Out[87]: 
0     1N
1     1N
2     1N
3     1N
4     2N
5     2S
6    NaN
7    NaN
8     4S
9     4S
Name: NCU, dtype: object
```

Please let me know if I can add more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simpliest solution is cast column to `string` - then is possible use `str.upper` or `str.replace`:

```
data_frame['column_name'] = data_frame['column_name'].astype(str)
data_frame['column_name'] = data_frame['column_name'].str.replace('n', 'N')
data_frame['column_name'] = data_frame['column_name'].str.replace('s', 'S')
print (data_frame)
  column_name
0          1N
1          1N
2          1N
3          1N
4          2N
5          2S
6           3
7           3
8          4S
9          4S
```

**But if need numeric with strings together**:

I think you need [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html), because you have mixed values - numeric with strings and [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) return `NaN` where numeric values (bur works another solution with `mask`):

```
data_frame['column_name'] = data_frame['column_name'].replace(['n', 's'],
                                                              ['S','N'],
                                                              regex=True)
print (data_frame)
  column_name
0          1S
1          1S
2          1S
3          1S
4          2S
5          2N
6           3
7           3
8          4N
9          4N
```

Another solution is filter only `string` and use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`str.upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.upper.html):

```
mask = data_frame['column_name'].apply(type) == str
data_frame['column_name'] = data_frame['column_name'].mask(mask,
                            data_frame['column_name'].str.upper())
print (data_frame)
  column_name
0          1N
1          1N
2          1N
3          1N
4          2N
5          2S
6           3
7           3
8          4S
9          4S
```

Another solution is replace `NaN` by [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
upper = data_frame['column_name'].str.upper()
data_frame['column_name'] = upper.combine_first(data_frame['column_name'])
#alternative solution
#data_frame['column_name'] = upper.fillna(data_frame['column_name'])
  column_name
0          1N
1          1N
2          1N
3          1N
4          2N
5          2S
6           3
7           3
8          4S
9          4S
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael, I had to convert the datatype to str. Its been awhile with pandas, I thought the 'object' datatype was the same type of string.

Comment: Yes, it is obviously string. But not always, you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672552/pandas-cast-column-to-string-does-not-work/42672574#42672574)