# How to cast all objects to str in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change all columns of type object to str and I do not understand why this command does not work:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=["object"]) = df.select_dtypes(include=
["object"]).astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, because [obviously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42672574/2901002) `object` `dtype` is `string`.

You can test it by:

```
print (df.select_dtypes(include=["object"]).applymap(type))
```