# How to do column string concatenation including space separator in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am a Pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,2 ,3],
    'txt1': ['Hello there1', 'Hello there2', 'Hello there3'],
    'txt2': ['Hello there4', 'Hello there5', 'Hello there6'],
    'txt3': ['Hello there7', 'Hello there8', 'Hello there9']
})
df

id  txt1            txt2            txt3
1   Hello   there1  Hello there4    Hello there7
2   Hello   there2  Hello there5    Hello there8
3   Hello   there3  Hello there6    Hello there9
```

I want to concatenate column `txt1`, `txt2`, and `txt3`. So far I am able to achieve it as follows:

```
df['alltext'] = df['txt1']  + df['txt2'] + df['txt3']
df

id  txt1            txt2            txt3            alltext
1   Hello there1    Hello there4    Hello there7    Hello there1Hello there4Hello there7
2   Hello there2    Hello there5    Hello there8    Hello there2Hello there5Hello there8
3   Hello there3    Hello there6    Hello there9    Hello there3Hello there6Hello there9
```

but how to introduce **space** character between the two column strings while concatenating in Pandas?

I have just started learning Pandas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also add separator between columns:

```py
df['alltext'] = df['txt1']  + ' ' + df['txt2'] + ' ' + df['txt3']
```

Or filter by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) only columns with `txt` in column name and use `join` per rows with `apply`:

```py
df['alltext'] = df.filter(like='txt').apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

Or filter only object columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) - most times a `Series` with a dtype of object is going to be a `string` - but it could be any [`Python object`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42672574/2901002):

```py
df['alltext'] = df.select_dtypes('object').apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

Or select columns by positions - all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```py
df['alltext'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

Thank you, @Jon Clements for solution for better matching columns names with `txt` and numeric:

```py
df['alltext'] = df.filter(regex=r'^txt\d+$').apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

Comment: One might want to consider `.filter(regex=r'^txt\d+$')` just to be explicit about exactly what columns are wanted rather than the off-chance of `like='txt'` picking up something not wanted... (although - it'd be rather improbable that'd be case here)

Comment: Slight nitpick... *obviously objects are strings* - Not quite true... they're objects that aren't of a numpy type... they could be (although unlikely in most cases) be *anything* rather than string - hence applying `str.join` to 'em will break. (Mind you - if you're storing silly stuff in a DF/array, then that's a whole different problem in itself :p)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add **space** between that,

```
df['alltext'] = df['txt1']  + ' ' + df['txt2'] + ' ' + df['txt3']
```