# Multiplying dataframes with same size and index

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue multiplying 2 dataframes as follows with the same number of columns and rows. Both are filled with a float64 data type. It output an empty dataframe. Any contribution could help, please.

`pos` dataframe:

```
          2019-03-01    2019-03-02    2019-03-03    
currency                                                                                                                                  
1WO       2.600000e+02  2.600000e+02  2.600000e+02  
ADH       8.219730e+02  8.219730e+02  8.219730e+02
```

`c_price` dataframe:

```
timestamp      2019-03-01  2019-03-02  2019-03-03  
currency                                                                                                                                                       
1WO            1.8140      1.7230      1.7250      
ADH            0.2425      0.2465      0.2387
```

my code:

```
jpy_bal = pos * c_price
```

`df.columns.dtype` output for both df:

```
object
```

`df.dtypes` output for both df:

```
2019-03-01    float64
2019-03-02    float64
2019-03-03    float64
2019-03-04    float64
2019-03-05    float64
           ...   
2019-11-01    float64
2019-11-02    float64
2019-11-03    float64
2019-11-04    float64
2019-11-05    float64
Length: 250, dtype: object
```

Comment: What is `print (pos.columns.dtype)
print (c_price.columns.dtype)` ?

Comment: @jezrael I think you have posted something but it is gone. It helped me. It should be here.

Comment: hmmm, all things what are in my mind are in answer...

Comment: @jezrael I though this could be dtype too at first. But look my edit for dtype check. It is the same for both df. This output told me the problem is not dtype, but it was as your solution works. What is the reasoning here?

Comment: So if use `pos.columns = pd.to_datetime(pos.columns)
c_price.columns = pd.to_datetime(c_price.columns)` it help?

Comment: @jezrael Yes it helped. I am just trying to understand why it was the dtype. The dtype check is same output for both df...

Comment: hmmm, are same types `print (type(pos.columns[0])) 
print (type(c_price.columns[0]))` ?

Comment: @jezrael This is the output <class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'datetime.date'>

Comment: So it is reason, need same - both dates or both datetimes.

Comment: @jezreal Ok, if my understanding is good. All the dtype has to be the same. Not only values but also columns labels and index. Correct?

Comment: exactly, but because objects should be different, then have to match types

Comment: it is same principe like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672552/pandas-cast-column-to-string-does-not-work/42672574#42672574) - same dtypes objects, but different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are different dtypes in columns:

```
print (pos.columns.dtype) 
print (c_price.columns.dtype)
```

So need convert them to same dtype, here `DatetimeIndex` in columns:

```
pos.columns = pd.to_datetime(pos.columns)
c_price.columns = pd.to_datetime(c_price.columns)
jpy_bal = pos * c_price
```

Another problem should be different index values - maybe trailing whitespaces:

```
pos.index = pod.index.str.strip()
c_price.index = c_price.index.str.strip()
```

---

Another idea is multiple by numpy array:

```
jpy_bal = pos * c_price.values
```

Or:

```
jpy_bal = pos.values * c_price
```

```
print (jpy_bal)
     2019-03-01  2019-03-02  2019-03-03
1WO  471.640000  447.980000  448.500000
ADH  199.328452  202.616344  196.204955
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
jpy_bal = pd.DataFrame(pos.values * c_price.values, columns=pos.columns, index=pos.index)
```