# Query about datetime64[ns] and Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
import sys
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

start=dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end=dt.datetime(2018,12,31)

#importing financial data from yahoo
df=web.DataReader('SFR.AX', 'yahoo', start, end) 

#when importing you get Date as index. I dont want that so I put Date as a column and reset the indexes
df=df.reset_index(drop=False) 

#info tells me Date column is datetime64[ns] dtype
print df.info()

#but when I use type() on the 1st element of df['Date'] it tells me <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
print type(df['Date'][0])
```

I don't get it, what is Date column exactly? datetime64[ns] or Timestamp? As far as I know they are different. Thanks in advance

[image: executing]

Comment: It depends what looking for - `dtype` is `datetime64[ns]` and `type` is `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`

Comment: Then why there are functions to convert between datetime64[ns] and TimeStamp if they refer to different concepts? @jezrael

Comment: hmmm, maybe it depends what need, can you be more specific?

Comment: not clear `if they refer to different concepts?`

Comment: Aren't dtype and type different things? Then why you can convert between datetime64[ns] (dtype) and TimeStamp (type) using certain functions? If you take a datetime64[ns] dtype variable and use one of this converting functions, its new dtype will be pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp? But isn't Timestamp a possible value for type and not dtype?

Comment: yes, you are right, it is different things, similar is object dtypes and many different types - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672552/pandas-cast-column-to-string-does-not-work/42672574#42672574)