# Name of data types in DataFrame Python?

Tags: python, pandas, types

I have one simple question about types of data in Pandas DataFrame:

A column which has values like:

```
1, 
22, 
56, 
66
```

is a numerical values column.
What is a type of values in column which has values like this:

```
radio, 
TV, 
Car
```

and so on ?

Comment: `int`? `string`?

Comment: Beware there are two different things here: the type of the value and the dtype of the column. A column with an int dtype (int32 or int64 for example) can only contain integer values. A column with a floating point type (float32 or float64) can only contain floating point values, including NaN. But a column with `object` dtype can contain any value, be it string, integer or float.

Comment: Maybe help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672552/pandas-cast-column-to-string-does-not-work/42672574#42672574)

Comment: Have you looked at the Pandas docs?

Comment: I reformatted the entities into a visible column. This display should be more intuitive.